# Comunicacion entre componentes Angular

Tags: angularjs-2.0, typescript, angular4

Soy nuevo en Angular ,Estoy tratando de pasar un valor de una pantalla a otra. La cosa va asi :
En la primera pantalla selecciono de un "select" un valor (es el id de un cliente) , luego hago un click en un botón y me redirige a otra pagina en donde necesito el id del cliente para poder trabajar. ¿como puedo hacer esto? He visto formas con input (pero son 2 pantallas diferentes ) y con observables(no se guarda el id de mi cliente) pero no me funcionan , debido a que creo que se necesita que las 2 pantallas estén activas a la vez.

Les muestro mi service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()

export class CommunicationService {

  private idCliente = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1232);

  cast = this.idCliente.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

   editidCliente(newCliente)

{this.idCliente.next(newCliente);

   }

}
```

En la primera pantalla cambia el valor y lo cambia correctamente, pero cuando habro la segunda siempre me muestra el valor con que inicializo en este caso "1232".

Asi lo estoy usando en la primera pantalla :

```
import { CommunicationService} from './communication.service';
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: "....",
  styles: [],
  providers : [...,CommunicationService],


})

export class RegistrarPropuestaComponent implements OnInit {

...
  public idCliente : any ; 
....
    constructor(... private communicationService : CommunicationService) { }



  ngOnInit() { 
    ....
    this.communicationService.cast.subscribe(cliente => this.idCliente=cliente)
...
  }
  changeidCliente(idCliente){  //esto se ejecuta en el change del select
    console.log("valor del idCliente despues del cambio en el select: " + idCliente);
    this.communicationService.editidCliente(idCliente);
  }
```

y asi en mi seguna pantalla que es donde quiero obtener el valor de idCliente para poder trabajar .

```
import { CommunicationService} from './communication.service';
    @Component({
      selector: '...',
      templateUrl: "....",
      styles: [],
      providers : [...,CommunicationService],


    })

    export class RegistrarPropuestaComponent implements OnInit {

    ...
      public idCliente : any ; 
    ....
        constructor(... private communicationService : CommunicationService) { }



      ngOnInit() { 
        ....
        this.communicationService.cast.subscribe(cliente => this.idCliente=cliente)
    ...
      }
```

Como verán es casi idéntico .

Comment: Puedes colocar como haces uso de ese servicio? porque tal vez ahí este el problema. Debes suscribirte (`subscribe()`) a ese observable.